Have any Congresspersons said they are completely against all forms of vaccine?
Somewhat related to this answer, based on a quick look at the positions of some Congresspersons, they could get [and they do get] labeled 'vaccine skeptics' [by critics].
I'm wondering if any of them [Congresspersons] go further than that though, and completely deny the usefulness of all vaccines, so as to count as part of the real/elite anti-vaxxers (in Trump's wordbook)?

If by "all forms of vaccines" you mean not just the COVID-19 vaccine, then yes, there are a few examples.
But it is a fairly common tactic of anti-vaccine activists to make broad anti-vaccine comments and then follow up with, "well, some vaccines are fine" without actually saying what the good ones are, or to say they're "just asking questions." So I doubt you'll find a congressman actually saying something as blunt as, "I oppose even a single person getting a vaccine of any kind." At the end of the day, politicians are politicians, and most people want vaccines.
That said, here's some examples of vaccine denial/skepticism, divorced from the COVID context:

Tennessee Congressman Mark Green (R) - said that vaccines cause
autism in 2018, without distinguishing one form or the other.
When pressed, he issued a statement saying, in part, "Vaccines are
essential to good population health."
Florida Congressman Bill Posey (R) - accused the CDC of covering up a link between vaccines and autism in 2015, and promoted an anti-vaccine documentary on Facebook in 2016. Still claims to be personally "pro-vaccine."



Kentucky Senator Rand Paul (R)- This is a borderline case. Paul opposed vaccine mandates long before COVID, but on libertarian grounds. That said, he said during the 2016 primaries that his stance was informed by the fact that "I have heard of many tragic cases of walking, talking normal children who wound up with profound mental disorders after vaccines." He subsequently walked it back quite a bit, and even sent out a photo of himself getting a vaccine.
Indiana Congressman Dan Burton (R)- Per Roll Call in 2012, "For more than a decade, Indiana Republican Dan Burton has been a leading House voice on autism and a proponent of the theory that mercury in vaccines contributes to the disorder. He held at least 20 hearings examining the potential link..."
Minnesota Congresswoman Michelle Bachmann: Said during her presidential run that the HPV vaccine causes "mental retardation."
New York Congresswoman Carolyn Maloney (D)- Apologized in 2022 for her past anti-vaccine stance, which she expressed in both House hearings and submitted bills. Among the quotes circulated by her opponents: "There’s too much verbal evidence coming from parents where they break down, ‘I had a normal child, I gave him a vaccination, and then they… came down with autism."


The "vaccines cause autism" link was originally claimed specically for the MMR vaccines that all children are expected to get before going to public school.

And of course it's well known that the study that claimed this was debunked (the scientist was being paid by people with a lawsuit against a vaccine manufacturer) and the paper was retracted.
